# Trying to remove a circle with a delay. End up with an error. [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3

```
        public function Main():void 
    {

        trace(ary);
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 150; i++)
        {
            ary[i] = i * 2 + 1;
            var line:TextField = new TextField();
            line.text = ary[i];
            line.x = i * 20;
            addChild(line);
        }
        var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(25,100);  
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, circleSpawnAndRemove);
        myTimer.start();

    }
```

This is my main function which contains an array aswell as a timer. Every time the timer runs it is supposed to create a circle with a certain size, wait 24 milliseconds and remove it again.

```
        public function circleSpawnAndRemove(e:TimerEvent):void
    {

        ball.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF * Math.sin(0.1 * i), 0.5);
        ball.graphics.drawCircle(tel, 300 , kaas);
        ball.graphics.endFill();

        trace (i);
        addChild(ball);
        tel = 400;
        kaas = ((125 - (Math.sin(50 * i) * 125 )) + 10)
        i++

        var remover:Timer = new Timer(24);  
        remover.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, ballRemover);
        remover.start();

        function ballRemover(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            if ( i > 1 )
            {
                removeChild(ball[i]);
            }

            else
            {
                trace("stresss")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that spawns a circle. When it attempts to remove the ball it displays the following error. (translated) "The given displayobject must be a child of the caller"

Comment: ball[i] would refer to an element on an array but you don't have a ball array. I'm not convinced you need another timer nested in your initial timer handler either. Could you not just remove the previous ball directly before the new one is spawned?

Comment: As a side note: anonymous functions like your ballRemover() are bad coding practice in AS3. make it a private function instead and don't forget to remove the eventlistener when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First up, it's not clear, from your code, what 'ball' is defined as.
If it's an Array, then the line...

```
addChild(ball);
```

...is attempting to add an Array to the stage. Arrays are not display objects, so this is not possible.
If it is NOT an Array, then the line...

```
removeChild(ball[i]);
```

...will throw an error, because, whatever type of Class it is, it is unlikely to use index notation like an Array.
So, you need to figure out what Class 'ball' is and stick with one usage of it.

I'd suggest making ball a Shape variable local to the circleSpawnAndRemove function and remove the '[i]' from the removeChild line:

```
var ball:Shape = new Shape();
ball.graphics....

..removeChild(ball)
```

There are a couple other potential problems with your code; For instance, the 'tel' and 'kaas' variables aren't set until after you use them. But let me know if you need more help with that.